# jQuery: Change margin setting of a class selector based on screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I want to do is start out with 3000px in jQuery and for every 100px pixels less than that i want to take away 5px from a `margin-top:60px`.

So.....

Say someone comes in with a screen that is 2500px wide, I want jQuery to say ok that is 500px less than the initial 3000px so I am going to take away 25px from `.container {margin-top:60px;}` and make it `.container {margin-top:35px;}`

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle

Comment: I don't even know where to start. That is why I am asking for "help". You know aid in learning where to even start. I see people on here all the time that don't even know where to begin that ask for help. I will try some things on my own then and come back. Or i will just ask somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following jquery you can assign the margin dynamically.

```
$(window).resize(function(){ 
var newval = parseInt($(window).width() * 0.02); /* (60/3000 = 0.02) */
$('.container').css('margin-top',newval);
});
```

Comment: That did it with a little tweaking of the 0.02 I got it to work on all different screen sizes. Thank you so much for your help even though I didn't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got what you mean:

```
var _window=$(window).width()<3000?$(window).width():3000;
```

You can set your container width to this variable _window

Comment: For container's style: if($(window).width()<3000){$(".container").css({"margin-top":"60px"});}else{$(".container").css({"margin-top":60*($(window).width()/3000)+"px"})}